# Kofax server throws error "VRS failed with error -136"

Tags: c#, kofax

Kofax server throws error "VRS failed with error -136" when a job is submitted with index fields and works fine when job is submitted without index fields. I suspect some configuration issue on the kofax server setup but unable find which configuration is causing it throw error -136

Comment: That's a bit vague to actually suggest something useful. Best would be to contact Kofax Support (after having consulted the [Knowledge Base](https://knowledge.kofax.com/)).

Comment: Can you lookup what VRS error 136 encodes? My access has expired, so I cannot look it up. Your license is valid, right?

Comment: License is valid and also I seached for this error code. No help found.

Comment: "VRS failed with error -136" is observed with imported file format is multipage tif file from a scanned job is uploaded. So looks like kofax is unable to import and process scanned output file format is a multi-page tiff. So not sure why it fails for multi page tiff file.